# Counting and returning mean in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm doing the Titanic Kaggle problem.

I'm trying to return both count & sum in the same query against my dataset. I know I have to use the `.agg` function somewhere in my query but I cannot figure out where.

`SexI` is a column which relates to the passenger sex and `AgeCat` is a column I created to better communicate the Age data:

```
df[['AgeCat', 'SexI', 'PropSurvive']].groupby(['SexI','AgeCat'], as_index=False).agg(['mean', 'count']).sort_values(by=['SexI','AgeCat'], ascending=True)
```

So, in this query, when I replace `agg(['mean', 'count'])` with `.mean` returns kind of what I want, which is the mean of the survive for the different groups i'm analyzing. When I replace with `.count`, it returns a count.

But I cannot get them both to return in the same query. Right now it's giving me a KeyError: `'SexI'` , but I do not really see how.

Btw is this similar to an SQL query where you'd `select count(ROW) & mean(ROW)`?

Comment: Is possible add some sample data with expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and add column `PropSurvive` to list after `groupby`:

```
(df.groupby(['SexI','AgeCat'])['PropSurvive']
   .agg(['mean', 'count'])
   .reset_index() 
   .sort_values(by=['SexI','AgeCat'], ascending=True))
```

Comment: ['Survived', 'Pclass', 'Name', 'Sex', 'Age', 'SibSp', 'Parch', 'Ticket', 'Fare', 'Cabin', 'Embarked', 'SexI', 'FareCat', 'AgeCat']

Comment: if i replace    .agg(['mean', 'count']) with .count or .mean, it works...

Comment: There is no type.

Comment: I have idea, try reset_index

Comment: @user3042850 - There is problem `as_index=False` should not return Multiindex, but it return. so reset_index help.